# Why is a link being separated from the rest of my "About Me"?

Tags: support, user-card

Recently I hit 1,000 rep on Stack Overflow so I went to remind myself of what privileges I got (because I knew I would be getting some) and saw that the main thing I was getting was my expanding usercard (because seeing up/downvote totals I've been doing via a Chrome Addon).

Seeing as how I totally forgot about this on [Anime and Manga](http://anime.stackexchange.com) where I have everything (for now) minus mod powers (again, for now) I went to see what it looked like.

[image: screen shot]

Something caught my eye though. I knew my "About Me" stuff would get chopped off but there was a link there which should not be showing because it's close to the bottom.

[image: screen shot]

As you can see not only is the link at the bottom and a far bit away from where my usercard cuts off my "About Me" but it's also totally ignoring that there's text around it.

So why is a link being separated from the rest of my "About Me" and displayed? Would it still do this if I used `<!-- summary: [your text here] -->` given that HTML doesn't work in it?

Answer (score 4):

Any links *inside* the section of your profile that is shown will be rendered as normal within the text, but any links *outside* of that are separated and shown on their own below.

From the Help Center [Established User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) page:

> #### What information is shown on the expanded usercard?
>
> - Your **About Me** section. Up to the first 298 characters will be displayed as the meat of your expanded usercard. HTML links and linebreaks/paragraphs will be rendered, but not formatting such as bold.
> - Any **additional HTML links** will be displayed and linked at the bottom of the expanded usercard. This does not repeat any links that are already shown in the previous part.

I just tested and the links still show if you use the `<!-- summary: -->` comment syntax.